# Can Geoprocessing Services be consumed within ArcGIS Online?

Tags: geoprocessing, arcgis-online, geoprocessing-service, geoprocessing-package

I have a geoprocessing package in my ArcGIS Online account for my organization which can be downloaded and used within ArcGIS for Desktop.

Are similar functions available to enable Geoprocessing Services be consumed within the ArcGIS Online environment?

Answer (score 1):

A geoprocessing package (.gpk) is **how you share your geoprocessing workflows**.

*(it is like sharing a model)*

You can only run it with ArcGIS Desktp or Server (as a geoprocessing service)

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00570000004p000000
[image]

10.2
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00570000003t000000